# Infinite loop struggle for a beginner

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I need to change the condition so that the loop is finite and list_ contains following values:

1 2 4 8 16 32 64

This is what I have in python, and I am struggling to understand what exactly needs to be changed and why.

```
list_ = []
i = 0
while i >= 0: # change the condition
  list_.append(2 ** i)
  i += 1
print(list_)
```

Comment: `while i <= 8`?

Comment: i think you only need to switch to add an upper bound to while loop

Comment: yep, while `i <= 6` works

Comment: "I am struggling to understand what exactly needs to be changed and why." Well, there is a comment in the code that says "change the condition" - presumably that was given to you as part of the assignment. I would guess that it means, you should change something on that line. Right? Now - do you understand what "the condition" means? What part of the line is "the condition"? Keeping this in mind, what seems to be wrong with it? (Why does the loop run infinitely? What is your understanding of how `while` loops work?)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a `for`-loop instead of a `while` loop.

```py
list_ = []
for i in range(7):
    list_.append(2 ** i)
    
print(list_)
```

If you want to be very pythonic, then you can use a list comprehension:

```py
list_ = [2 ** i for i in range(7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `while` a breaking condition is required (this implementation is to highlight the `break`)

```
out = []
i = 0
while True:
    if i > 6:
        break
    out.append(2**i)
    i += 1
print(out)
```

or with a list comprehension

```
print([2**i for i in range(6+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll only need to switch the `while` condition in the loop. Rather than have a lower bound, you'll need to update with an upper bound - basically a "loop until" condition.

```
list_ = []
i = 0
while i <= 6: # change the condition
  list_.append(2 ** i)
  i += 1
print(list_). # [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

But you can simplify this even further, with the help of a `list` comprehension. This is just a fancy (and bit more efficient) way of writing a `for` loop in python. Its more efficient because it doesn't need to call `list.append` within each loop iteration.

```py
>>> [2 ** i for i in range(7)]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while i <= 6:` so that you while loop counts up to i=6.
However, I would recommend to use a for-loop with range(6) as a condition. So that your loop looks like the following:

```
for i in range(7):
    …
```

This is just an alternative way, where i also counts up to the value of 6. using a for-loop would be good practice, as it saves you to declare i previously.